# Why doesn't my sorting function work? (Google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have defined the following function in the scripteditor

```
function SORTBYLEN(input) {
    return Array.isArray(input) ?
        input.sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length): input
}
```

I would expect to be able to give it a range of strings and it would return the range sorted by string length, yet when I try to use it, nothing changes.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that the reason of your issue is due to that `input` is 2 dimensional array. By this, the length of each element is `1`. So the array of `input` is not sorted. In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
return Array.isArray(input) ? input.sort((a, b) => a[0].length - b[0].length) : input;
```

or

```
return Array.isArray(input) ? input.flat().sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length) : input;
```

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)